# Using Selenium and python to save a table

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium with Python to store the contents of a table. My script is as follows:

```
import sys
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://testsite.com")

value = selenium.getTable("table_id_10")

print value

driver.close()
```

This opens up the webpage I am interested in, and then should save the contents of the table that I want. I've seen the syntax in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903144/using-seleniums-python-api-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table) which uses `browser.get_table()`, but the beginning of that program begins with `browser=Selenium(...)` which I did not understand. I'm not sure what syntax I should be using as `selenium.getTable("table_id_10")` is incorrect.

---

EDIT:

I included a html snippet of the table that I am using:

```
<table class="datatable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table_id_10" style="width:70%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <caption>
        <span class="captioninformation right"><a href="Services.aspx" class="functionlink">Return to Services</a></span>Data
    </caption><tr>
        <th scope="col">Read Date</th><th class="numericdataheader" scope="col">Days</th><th class="numericdataheader" scope="col">Values</th>

    </tr><tr>
        <td>10/15/2011</td><td class="numericdata">92</td><td class="numericdata">37</td>
    </tr><tr class="alternaterows">
        <td>7/15/2011</td><td class="numericdata">91</td><td class="numericdata">27</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>4/15/2011</td><td class="numericdata">90</td><td class="numericdata">25</td>    
</table>
```

Comment: If you're looking to web-scrape (I think that's what you're doing), you might also want to look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). I've used it in the past and really like it, but unfortunately the documentation is lacking quite a bit and it's a little difficult to use. Just a thought, hope it isn't too off topic.

Comment: @TKKocheran I am interested in scraping, though in this case it is just one table. I would also be fine saving the html page and parsing it separately later.

Comment: You might want to look into using mechanize then. Once you get the hang of it, mechanize is uber-powerful at doing stuff. I once wrote a script which would log into my bank account, answer a security question, then proceed to grab my financial data using a form available in the banking application. Fun stuff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The old Selenium RC API included a `get_table` method:

```
In [14]: sel=selenium.selenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox", "http://www.google.com/webhp")
In [19]: sel.get_table?
Type:       instancemethod
Base Class: <type 'instancemethod'>
String Form:    <bound method selenium.get_table of <selenium.selenium.selenium object at 0xb728304c>>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py
Definition: sel.get_table(self, tableCellAddress)
Docstring:
    Gets the text from a cell of a table. The cellAddress syntax
    tableLocator.row.column, where row and column start at 0.

    'tableCellAddress' is a cell address, e.g. "foo.1.4"
```

Since you are using the newer Webdriver (a.k.a Selenium 2) API, that code does not apply.

---

Perhaps try something like this instead:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def quitting(thing):
    yield thing
    thing.close()
    thing.quit()

with quitting(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    data = []
    for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="table_id_10"]//tr'):
        tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        if tds: 
            data.append([td.text for td in tds])
print(data)
# [[u'10/15/2011', u'92', u'37'], [u'7/15/2011', u'91', u'27'], [u'4/15/2011', u'90', u'25']]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `get_table` did not work. I added a snippet of the html table - I'm trying to pull out all of the values from the cells.

Comment: +1 for including `contextlib`.  I didn't realize this was a thing until now.  I'm going to have to convert all my scripts to work this way :D

Comment: @DuckPuncher: For some versions of webdriver, you [may need to call both `close` and `quit`](http://seleniumsimplified.com/2013/08/faq-why-has-my-firefox-selenium-webdriver-browser-not-closed/). I've updated the code above to show a context manager which does both.

Comment: @unutbu, this is great!