# Python Parsing HTML Table Generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table from the NYSE website (http://www1.nyse.com/about/listed/IPO_Index.html) into a pandas dataframe.  In order to do so, I have a setup like this:

```
def htmltodf(url):
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

tables = soup.findAll('table')
test = pandas.io.html.read_html(str(tables))

return(test)            #return dataframe type object
```

However, when I run this on the page, all of the table returned in the list are essentially empty.  When I further investigated, I found that the table is generated by javascript.  When using the developer tools in my web browser, I see that the table looks like any other HTML table with the  tags, etc.  However, a view of the source code revealed something like this instead:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

.
.
.

<script>
var year = [["ICC","21st Century Oncology Holdings, Inc.","22 May  2014","/about/listed/icc.html" ],
... more entries here ...
,["ZOES","Zoe's Kitchen, Inc.","11 Apr 2014","/about/listed/zoes.html" ]] ;

    if(year.length != 0) 
    {   

    document.write ("<table width='619' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><span class='fontbold'>");
    document.write ('2014' + " IPO Showcase"); 
    document.write ("</span></td></tr></table>"); 
    }  
</script>
```

Therefore, when my HTML parser goes to look for the table tag, all it can find is the if condition, and no proper   tags below that would indicate content.  How can I scrape this table?  Is there a tag that I can search for instead of table that will reveal the content?  Because the code is not in traditional html table form, how do I read it in with pandas--do I have to manually parse the data?

Comment: I don't think you can with BS. Maybe try selenium? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960288/get-page-generated-with-javascript-in-python

Comment: Did you use splinter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143023/using-selenium-and-python-to-save-a-table may be this will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, you need something to run that javascript code for you.

One option here would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www1.nyse.com/about/listed/IPO_Index.html')

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sp5"]/table//table/..')
table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')

df = read_html(table_html)[0]
print df

driver.close()
```

prints:

```
                                                    0        1          2   3
0                                                Name   Symbol        NaT NaN
1                       Performance Sports Group Ltd.      PSG 2014-06-20 NaN
2                           Century Communities, Inc.      CCS 2014-06-18 NaN
3                        Foresight Energy Partners LP     FELP 2014-06-18 NaN
...
79  EGShares TCW EM Long Term Investment Grade Bon...     LEMF 2014-01-08 NaN
80  EGShares TCW EM Short Term Investment Grade Bo...     SEMF 2014-01-08 NaN

[81 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: How do you find the input for `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`? I'm trying to scrape yahoo fantasy.

Comment: @riders994 You can get it by inspecting the web page.