# Obtain Web Table Data

Tags: jquery, html, pandas, html-table, ncbi

I want to obtain the values from a query at NCBI database. The page from which I want to extract the table is [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=%22PROTEIN+FATE%22](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=%22PROTEIN%20FATE%22)

I've tried to obtain the tables via LibreOffice and Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=%22PROTEIN+FATE%22")
```

On both situations, the resullts are:

[image]

[image]

However, instead of "searching", I was expecting to obtain the numeric values as shown:
[image]

Is there any intuitive way of doing this?

Thx!

Comment: Looks like those values are updated by JavaScript after the page loads.

Comment: Have you tried to use Beautifull soup ? Here is a related topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062365/python-parsing-html-table-generated-by-javascript