# collect table using pandas python, no table defined in html no tr or td

Tags: python, pandas, html-table

i tried to collect table from hydro one : https://stormcentre.hydroone.com/reports/1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659
it did work fine for different website,,,,wondering if pandas can get table from class html or role
seems class is : ReactVirtualized__Table__headerRow

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

from zipfile import ZipFile

df = pd.read_html('https://stormcentre.hydroone.com/reports/1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659')

for i, table in enumerate(df):
    table.insert(0, "time", dt.datetime.now(), True)
    table.to_csv('HydroExport.csv', ',', index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


print(table.to_string(index=False))

document = table.to_dict(orient='list')
print(document)
```

got error no table found

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3417, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-148a9ae7cc2f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/medsa/OneDrive/Documents/Py/datapython/Ch04/04_02/ImportHydroOne.py', wdir='C:/Users/medsa/OneDrive/Documents/Py/datapython/Ch04/04_02')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/medsa/OneDrive/Documents/Py/datapython/Ch04/04_02/ImportHydroOne.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html('https://stormcentre.hydroone.com/reports/1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659')
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1086, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 917, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 898, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 217, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\medsa\OneDrive\Documents\Py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 547, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

html code part of it

```
<div class="autosizer-wrapper" style="position: relative;"><div style="overflow: visible; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table report-table" role="grid"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__headerRow report-row odd" role="row" style="align-items: stretch; height: 50px; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px; width: 1009px;"><div aria-label="info-box-field-label-1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659-name" aria-sort="ascending" class="ReactVirtualized__Table__headerColumn name ReactVirtualized__Table__sortableHeaderColumn" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" style="flex: 1 1 400px;"><div class="kubra-table-header"><div class="header-label"><div class="name">Service Area:</div></div><div class="toggle-icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="caret-up" class="svg-inline--fa fa-caret-up fa-w-10 fa-sm className fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" data-glyph="caret-up" aria-label="caret-up"><path fill="currentColor" d="M288.662 352H31.338c-17.818 0-26.741-21.543-14.142-34.142l128.662-128.662c7.81-7.81 20.474-7.81 28.284 0l128.662 128.662c12.6 12.599 3.676 34.142-14.142 34.142z"></path></svg></div></div></div><div aria-label="info-box-field-label-1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659-cust_a" class="ReactVirtualized__Table__headerColumn cust-a ReactVirtualized__Table__sortableHeaderColumn" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" style="flex: 1 1 400px;"><div class="kubra-table-header"><div class="header-label"><div class="column-icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="exclamation-triangle" class="svg-inline--fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-w-18 fa-sm className fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-glyph="exclamation-triangle" aria-label="exclamation-triangle"><path fill="currentColor" d="M569.517 440.013C587.975 472.007 564.806 512 527.94 512H48.054c-36.937 0-59.999-40.055-41.577-71.987L246.423 23.985c18.467-32.009 64.72-31.951 83.154 0l239.94 416.028zM288 354c-25.405 0-46 20.595-46 46s20.595 46 46 46 46-20.595 46-46-20.595-46-46-46zm-43.673-165.346l7.418 136c.347 6.364 5.609 11.346 11.982 11.346h48.546c6.373 0 11.635-4.982 11.982-11.346l7.418-136c.375-6.874-5.098-12.654-11.982-12.654h-63.383c-6.884 0-12.356 5.78-11.981 12.654z"></path></svg></div><div class="name">Customers Affected:</div></div></div></div><div aria-label="info-box-field-label-1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659-cust_s" class="ReactVirtualized__Table__headerColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet ReactVirtualized__Table__sortableHeaderColumn" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" style="flex: 1 1 400px;"><div class="kubra-table-header"><div class="header-label"><div class="column-icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="user" class="svg-inline--fa fa-user fa-w-14 fa-sm className fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-glyph="user" aria-label="user"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="name">Customers Served:</div></div></div></div><div aria-label="info-box-field-label-1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659-etr" class="ReactVirtualized__Table__headerColumn etr ReactVirtualized__Table__sortableHeaderColumn" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" style="flex: 1 1 400px;"><div class="kubra-table-header"><div class="header-label"><div class="name">Estimated Restoration:</div></div></div></div></div><div aria-label="grid" aria-readonly="true" class="ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__Table__Grid" role="rowgroup" tabindex="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; position: relative; width: 1009px; will-change: transform; overflow: hidden; height: 614px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: auto; height: 300px; max-width: 1009px; max-height: 300px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row even" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">BANCROFT</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">222</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">26,765</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Aug 26, 2020, 2:15 AM</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row odd" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 50px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">BOWMANVILLE</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Fewer than 20</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">28,879</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Assessing Damage</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row even" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">DRYDEN</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Fewer than 20</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">12,132</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Assessing Damage</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row odd" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 150px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">MINDEN</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">699</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">20,096</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Aug 26, 2020, 2:15 AM</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row even" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 200px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">NEWMARKET</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Fewer than 20</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">60,070</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Assessing Damage</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row report-row odd" role="row" style="height: 50px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 250px; width: 1009px; align-items: stretch; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn name" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="level-1"><span class="clickable hyperlink-secondary " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">PICTON</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-a" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Fewer than 20</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn cust-s hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" " role="gridcell" tabindex="0">25,636</span></div></div><div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn etr" role="gridcell" style="flex: 1 1 400px; overflow: hidden;"><div class=""><span class=" hidden-lt-tablet" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">Reassessing</span><button type="button" class="report-modal-button hidden-gte-tablet" aria-label="Open Data Modal" title="Open Data Modal"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info" class="svg-inline--fa fa-info fa-w-6 fa-sm fa-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512" data-glyph="info" aria-label="info"><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 424.229h20V279.771H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20V212c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h112c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v212.229h20c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20V492c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20H20c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-47.771c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20zM96 0C56.235 0 24 32.235 24 72s32.235 72 72 72 72-32.235 72-72S135.764 0 96 0z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="resize-triggers"><div class="expand-trigger"><div style="width: 1010px; height: 665px;"></div></div><div class="contract-trigger"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're running into is that the page is dynamically generated. This becomes obvious if you try the following:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

target_url = 'https://stormcentre.hydroone.com/reports/1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659'

resp = requests.get(target_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
print(soup)
```

You'll notice that the HTML in the response only has a script tag in the body.

So your first challenge is parsing a table generated by JavaScript, where [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062365/python-parsing-html-table-generated-by-javascript) comes in very handy. It describes how to use the Python package Selenium for this task.

Once you fetch the HTML however, it becomes obvious that the generated HTML doesn't include a HTML table either. Instead, the table is actually built just by using <div> elements. So we need to specify which divs we want. I took some inspiration from [this guide](https://www.guru99.com/handling-dynamic-selenium-webdriver.html) which describes using an element's XPath to specify which element you want. Then I made use of CSS selectors as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660417/beautiful-soup-if-class-contains-or-regex) and [the official Beautiful Soup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Here's a suggested solution:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

target_url = 'https://stormcentre.hydroone.com/reports/1e44c6bf-cc63-4d4a-a68e-4dbd8bb63659'
# specify XPATH (I found this 'manually' using Firefox's Inspect Element tool
tablediv_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]'
# CSS selector/class pattern of table header/row elements
header_patt = '\"sortableHeaderColumn\"'
data_patt = '\"rowColumn\"'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# might have to wait a bit here
driver.get(target_url)

tablediv_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(tablediv_xpath)
tablediv_html = tablediv_el.get_attribute('innerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(tablediv_html)
headers = [el.text for el in soup.select(f'div[class*={header_patt}]')]
data = [el.text for el in soup.select(f'div[class*={data_patt}]')]
n_cols = len(headers)
n_datapoints = len(data)
# put the data in an array where each row/list corresponds to 
# one row of data in the table
data_arr = [data[x:x+n_cols] for x in range(0, n_datapoints, n_cols)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_arr, columns=headers)
```

```py
print(df)
#  Service Area: Customers Affected: Customers Served: Estimated Restoration:
#0      BANCROFT                 222            26,765  Aug 26, 2020, 9:00 AM
#...
```