# Python Selenium - How can I click on the third last element from a group of elements in a table?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Good day everyone,
Can someone explain to me how I cant get the number of elements in a table? I am running through multiple tables that all have different lengths and I always need the 3rd last item. I have the xpath of the table that contains those .

[Using Selenium's Python API - How do I get the number of rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903144/using-seleniums-python-api-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table)

I found this answer and some other answers that seem to answer my question, but to be honest: At this point I just dont understand how to implement this into my code.

I am using Python 3.6 and Selenium. Would be great if someone could help me out, since this little script could save me 1-2 hours of tedious work every day.

EDIT:

First I login to my Page, where I can search for CustomerIDs there I use the following Code:

```
Customer_IDs = ['100001','100002','100003']
for ID in Customer_IDs:

 customer = browser.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcustomercode')
 customer.send_keys(ID)
 customer.send_keys(Keys.TAB)    
 browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnsearch").click()

 #here I want go through the table to find the amount of rows

 browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_1").click()
 browser.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcustomercode').clear()
```

This "ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_1" is basically what I need to change. If there are 10 Rows I would need "ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_7" and so on.

### Update A (from comments)

I have the xpath of the table where the file is stored. The code that I have written works fine when I want the first element of that table ("ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_1"). But I need the third last element.

### Update B (from comments)

The xpath of the table is:

```
//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]
```

### Update C (from comments)

The xpaths for the rows are:

- `//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]/tbody/tr[1]`
- `//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]/tbody/tr[2]`

Comment: Share your current code, HTML sample, desired output

Answer (score 2):

To locate the **third last** row element with *id* starting as **ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_** you can use the following *xpath*:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1']/tbody/tr[last()-3]").click()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer correctly. I have the xpath of the table where the file is stored. The code that I have written works fine when I want the first element of that table ("ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_**1**"). But I need the third last element.

Comment: @Yarza Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: im getting an error message, but maybe I'm just too stupid to implement it properly.
the xpath of the table is: //*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: implemented exactly your comment into my existing code - got the following error message:
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[starts-with(@id,'ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview')][last()-3]"}"

Comment: When you land on the page and face the error, can you verify in the Development tools if the elements `ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1`, `ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview2` ... `ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview4` exists at-least?

Comment: And thanks for updating my question, I'm really kind of new to programming and stackoverflow. Will try to do better next time!

Comment: It's fine with me. Need your help to nail your issue at the earliest :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
To be honest, I dont fully understand your answer.
I dont think there are ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview2 and so on.

The xpaths for the rows are:
`//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]/tbody/tr[1]`,
`//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]/tbody/tr[2]`, ...

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I made a mistake, I'm sorry. The rows are called `[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1"]/tbody/tr[1]` But I just realized that the actual elements I want to access are: `ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_**XY**`.

Comment: Seems we are not reaching any where without the _HTML_. Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ for further analysis.

Comment: What exactly can I provide to help you? I'm currently inspecting the page. I can provide outerHTML, selector and xpath. Would that help you?

Comment: Is there no way to just count the rows in that table? So if it is for example 124 rows then I can click the element by just going for `"ContentPlaceHolder1_gridview1_refid_"&"124"` Or something similar.